# $X$ and $X \cup \{x\}$ equinumerous?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $X$ is an infinite set, possibly uncountably infinite, and $x \notin X$, how to prove that $X$ and $X \cup \{x\}$ are equinumerous? I do not know how to establish a bijection since I can not enumerate the elements of $X$. For $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N} \cup \{x\}$ the result is easy because it is countably infinite, but how to do it in general? Do we have to use the fact that every infinite set has a countable subset somehow? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the axiom of choice?

Comment: Yeah I think it should be fine to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $N\subset X$ countable. Then there is a bijection $\phi: N\cup\{x\}\rightarrow N$. Define $f:X\cup\{x\}\rightarrow X$ by $f(y)=y$  for $y\in X\backslash N$ and $f(y) = \phi(y)$ for $y \in N \cup\{x\}$. This is a bijection.

Comment: It's not relevant, but is "take $N\subset X$ countable" requires the axiom of choice?

Comment: @yanko: Yes, it requires at least Dependent Choice. The claim in the question is not provable from ZF alone -- there are models that contain [amorphous sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set), and an amorphous $X$ is _not_ equinumerous with $X\uplus\{x\}$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @HenningMakholm interesting thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Henning: Countable choice is enough, and in fact the statement every infinite set has a countable subset is strictly weaker than countable choice. So DC is definitely overkill.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I stand corrected.

Comment: @Henning: You may be seated now. ;)

Comment: @yanko: See my first comment on this thread, by the way.